# Jenkins, how to make only specific commits to SVN to trigger a build

Tags: jenkins

I am currently triggering a new Jenkins build whenever a commit to SVN has been made. However, I would like to make another build where our database is deployed only if the Ant script deploying the database OR our SQL scripts has been changed in SVN due to a commit. Is this possible to do in Jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this out of the box.  But you can achieve this through other means.

1. For the job, you only specify the SVN sources for which you would want to listen. The remaining svn sources can be added to the appropriate location using command line svn methods. Ensure that the command line execution will place and merge the existing sources that jenkins has got. You have to give the right destination options in the svn commands. I myself agree that this is not a very clean way to do, but at least there is a work around for that.
2. Have two jobs. The first job will be defined only on the required svn sources and you enable the poll option. This should trigger another downstream project which reads all source files. This job should not be polling svn and the actual build execution should be done here.

Comment: Excellent advice Shiva. I think I will go for option 2.